# Code should look in a folder and copy all used ranges in sheets "EntryList" to a master BUT why does it skip last rows from each sheet. need all rows

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wkbSource As Workbook, FolderName As String, lCol As Long, lRow As Long, FN As String, wbName As String
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select a folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
             MsgBox "You did not select a folder."
             Exit Sub
        End If
        FolderName = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    ChDir FolderName
    strExtension = Dir(".xls")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & strExtension)
        FN = Mid(Replace(FolderName, "\", ""), 19, 9999) ' Truncate from left the FolderName 19 times
        wbName = Split(wkbSource.Name, ".")(0)
        If Not IsError(Evaluate("=ISREF('[" & wkbSource.Name & "]" & "EntryList" & "'!$A$1)")) Then
            With Sheets("Entrylist")
            
                lRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                lCol = .Cells(25, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                .Range("A25").Resize(lRow - 25, lCol).Copy wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(lRow - 25) = FN & "-" & wbName ' String to print in Column A
            End With
        End If
        wkbSource.Close False
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    wsDest.Name = FN & "-" & "EntryList" 'Location and Season as the SheetName
    wsDest.Range("A1").Value = "NurseryName"
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit ' Text is still wraping
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter   'Working but unable to autofit columns
    'Rows("2:2").Select
    'Selection.FreezePanes = True  ' Not working
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FolderPath & FN & "-" & "EntryLists", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "BINGO!!!!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug it with F8 and see why does it not copy?

Comment: .Range("A25").Resize(lRow - 25, lCol).Copy

You subtract 25 from lRow?